# Using dot notation with number passed into function

Tags: javascript

If I have an object and function

```
var obj {
    "1234": {"example": "sample"},
    "5678": {"example": "sample"}
}    

function example(num, str) {
    if obj[num].hasOwnProperty(str) {
        //manipulate property
    }
    return obj;
}
```

then later call the function,

```
obj(1234, "example")
```

Why do I have to write obj[num] instead of obj.num? Shouldn't dot notation be acceptable because the value being passed will always be an integer and not have quotations around it, i.e. obj.1234 would work but not obj."string"?

Comment: Side note: If you want, you can drop the quotes on the property names in the object initializer. Numeric literals are valid there: `var obj = { 1234: {"example": "sample"} ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I have to write obj[num] instead of obj.num?

Because `obj[num]` takes the **value** of `num` (for instance, `1234`) and uses that value as the property name, but `obj.num` uses `"num"` (literally) as the property name. Brackets vs. dot is how the JavaScript parser knows when you're giving the property name literally (dot notation) or using an expression you want to use the result of (brackets notation).

---

(Side note: Granted, when we do `foo[1]`, we literally mean the property `1` in `foo`. But from the parser's perspective, we're effectively using an expression there.)